# linux high speed character detection rs232

Tags: linux, c, rs232

I have to do a code in C to detect the inter-characters time within a rs232 line on linux. Inter-characters time to detect could be 1ms. So I need something to timestamp very quickly an incomming characters. When I say very quickly is less than 1ms. The goal is to detect end of a frame and beginning of a new frame on the line.

I don't ask for a coding solution, I just want a initial help to know what path I have to take : is it possible to do this on linux ? I have to modify a driver to reach this kind of time ? Or Something on user space can do it (I don't think so).

Comment: Sounds like you want soft real-time behavior. It’ll be hard to even achieve that using PC hardware and software

Comment: Even if I modify the driver already in use (I will be closer from hardware...) ?

Comment: I would think you might be better off trying to capture the raw signals. For low bit-rates you may be able to use audio input, but for higher speeds you will need a high-speed A-D capture interface. In effect you need a software oscilloscope.

Comment: Thanks AFH, but I think there is a mistake. I don't want to do this C programm for debug, but to be able to detect a silent of 1ms for exemple between the reception of two character on the rs232 line. I want to do that because a silent of more than 1ms means end of a frame and beginning of a new frame.

Answer (score 1):

Is that an on-board UART, or an USB dongle? For the first, I'd modify the serial driver interrupt routine to store the data together with a timestamp, deliver the data with the timestamp to user space, and let user space sort it out. While Linux is not real-time, I'd expect it to be able to answer all interrupts in less than 1 ms, so that should be enough.

For an USB dongle, `usbmon` already provides timestamps in microseconds, so I guess on should be able to either use `usbmon` together with the normal serial USB driver, and modify the serial USB driver to make those timestamps accessible.

Comment: It's an on-board UART. This is my "favorite" solution too, because in my situation write a custom driver is easier than change hardware unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to do a code in C to detect the inter-characters time within a rs232 line on linux ...

You've posted an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> I want to do that because a silent of more than 1ms means end of a frame and beginning of a new frame.

(BTW in asynchronous serial communications such as RS-232, unqualified use of *"frame"* is ambiguous, since every character is framed.  E.G. when a UART reports a 'framing error', a character was (possibly) lost. Presumably you actually mean packet or message unit.)

Your additional comment finally reveals the actual X issue that needs solving.
Since the actual issue is detecting inter-message gaps, your original question about Y is not only difficult to accurately implement in software, but it is not even a viable solution to the X problem.

Any solution involving the "measuring" of the time interval between received characters by software to detect a inter-message gap is a flawed solution. This approach fails for the degenerate case:
when the last char of a message arrives and if there are no more chars (for a while), then that last received message is *stalled* indefinitely while the algorithm waits for the next char (the first byte of the next message) so that the time difference can be calculated.
As long as that "next char" is not received, then the "end of message" is not determined, and the last valid message is complete but not processed.

The proper solution is to use hardware that can measure when a character has, or rather has not, been received.  Some Atmel USARTs have a *Receiver Timeout* feature to detect the inter-message gap.

A possible software solution would require a (high-resolution) periodic timer that the U(S)ART driver would use to count time intervals between received characters.  Using PIO instead of DMA, the driver would have to reset the count of intervals as each char is received.  When the count exceeds a threshold (i.e. count * interval_time > inter_message_gap_time), then the receiver has been silent too long, indicating a inter-message gap.

Comment: *Any solution involving the "measuring" of the time interval between received characters by software to detect a inter-message gap is a flawed solution.* unfortunately MODBUS over serial line is such a thing, and probably not the only protocol doing so.

Comment: @pim -- I am aware of the MODBUS protocol, so what's your point?  Seems like you either didn't read the answer or you don't understand the issues involved.  The proper solution for such protocols is to detect a receive timeout, whereas timestamping characters and then calculating delta time (i.e. measuring the time interval) is flawed (i.e. doesn't work in every and all situations).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your  degenerate case : if I have a very quick solution that timestamp any incoming character,m ade by a low level layer. After, a user space programm will, sometime, read all characters avaiable, and with timestamp will determine a characters packet. This approach get around the degenerate case : when user space programm read last character available, it calculate,  with the timestamp and system uptime, since how many time character are available. And can determine if it's a character packet or not. I am wrong ?

Comment: *"when user space programm read last character available"* -- That's not reliable. This *"last character"* (depending on the *termios* configuration) could simply be a fragment of the message, rather than the end of the message. *"it calculate, with the timestamp and system uptime"* --  That calculation just gives the latency between interrupt level and your app; what good is that?  Besides, that latency can be significant (e.g. several milliseconds), especially when userspace is suspended. Therefore your calculation could generate false positives for the 1ms of silence on the wrong character.

Comment: @pim -- Here's a 3-year old answer to validate my rebuttal to your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152926/parsing-time-delimited-uart-data/27156684#27156684